# Core Data error message

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I created a Core Data Entity named: "Athlete".

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Athlete''
```

This is the line at where it breaks:

```
Athlete *detail = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Athlete" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

delegate.h

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

delegate.m

```
-(void)createData{

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    Athlete *detail = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Athlete" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    detail.first = @"Joe";

    detail.last = @"Pastrami";

    detail.phone = @"(123)456-7891";

    NSError *error;

    if(![context save:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Error :(");
    }

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Athlete" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSArray *arr = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    for (Athlete *ath in arr){
        NSLog(@"Name %@", ath.first);
    }

}



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self createData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all: your managedObjectContext is nil.

Comment: That's that thing. It shouldn't be nil. I don't know why it says that it is.

Comment: @JosueEspinosa Sometimes things don't work they way that you think they should.  That's where a stack trace and debugging comes in helpful.  Trace the stack back to where this method was called.  Do some debugging!!

Comment: You may want to watch the CS193p videos from Stanford. The teacher shows you how to setup a Core Data store using UIManagedDocument. It is quite simple once you understand how it's all set up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly passed your `managedObjectContext` object from `AppDelegate` to your  `UIViewController`? If not, 2 ways to do this:

1. From `AppDelegate` (example app with `UINavigationController` at root):

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
       NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

       UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController.navigationController;
       YourViewController *yourViewController = (SearchViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
       yourViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
       ...
   }
   ```
2. From `YourViewController`:

   ```
   #import AppDelegate.h
   ...
   @synthesize managedObjectContext;

   - (void)viewDidLoad
       AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
       managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
       ...
   }
   ```